# Using regular expressions for extracting messages from a source code

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Currently I'm trying to write a java program to extract messages from a plsql pkg file.

General message format of a pkg would be,

Type 01;

`Error_Msg.General_Message(pkg_name_,'INVALIDVALUE: The value 1,2 and 3 that you have entered is invalid.');`

But in some cases a message could be as follows,

Type 02:

```
Error_Msg.General_Message(pkg_name_,'INVALIDVALUE: The value :p you have entered is invalid.', Some_Pkg.Some_Function(parameter1, parameter2) );
```

NOTE: :p is a bind variable

Sometimes messages could be concatenated using '||' in plslql,

EX:

```
Error_Msg.General_Message(pkg_name_, 'This is a multiline'||'
     message');
```

I need to extract the only the text message, For an example in Type 01 the text I'm looking for is

> 'INVALIDVALUE: The value 1,2 and 3 that you have entered is invalid.'

I tried with this pattern,

```
\\s*(\\w+):\\s*[,-:\\w*\\s*\"\\.\\|\\'\\(\\)\\\\]+
```

But this would return a wrong result in the second message type.

Could somebody help me with this??

Thanks!

Comment: maybe search for the Error_Msg. string, then find the first ' then go to the end of the line and reverse search for the first '.  take everything in betweem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this?

```
\\s*(\\w+):\\s*(?:'\\s*\\|\\|\\s*'|[^'])+'
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tS7dK5)

`'\\s*\\|\\|\\s*'` will match the multiline part and allow the regex to continue matching.

Comment: Hi, Jerry I tried to modify the patter to catch messages such as 
Error_Msg.General_Message(pkg_name_, 'INVALIDVALUE: This is a multiline'p' message');

But I'm stuck with it still, Could suggest something on that ???

Comment: @pragan Is the `p` for multiline as well? If yes, then you can use `(?:\\|\\||p)` instead of `\\|\\|` in the regex. [Here's the updated demo](http://regex101.com/r/vJ3gF7)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it, It could be anything, 
Ex: This is a 'emphasize some text' message

I tried this \s*(\w+):\s*(?:'((\s*\|\||\s*)|\w*)'\s*|[^'])+'
but when you multiple words between '' it doesn't work

Thanks for all the support

Comment: I think following pattern works but I'm not sure it's the best way (I'm all new to regular expression)
\s*(\w+):\s*(?:'\s*(?:\|\||(\w*\s*)*)'\s*|[^'])+'

Comment: @pragan Oh, okay. Maybe something more like this? `\\s*(\\w+):\\s*(?:'\\s*(?:\\|\\||[^'\\n\\r]*)'\\s*|[^'])+'` I used another `[^']*` so that you don't have to use `(\w*\s*)*`. That construct can be dangerous and considerably slow the processing down. The `\\n\\r` inside is to prevent the match from spilling into other lines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47519/discussion-between-pragan-and-jerry)

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract everything between the first and second `'`? `String#substring` in combination with `String#indexOf` seems less cryptic.

Comment: But there could be 's in between the message as well,
Ex: 
Error_Msg.General_Message(pkg_name_, 'This is a multiline'||'
     message');

Comment: Crap - and what about the first and last?

Comment: That could be possible but it would fail in a scenario like,
Error_Msg.General_Message(pkg_name_,'INVALIDVALUE: The value :p you have entered is invalid.', Some_Pkg.Some_Function(parameter1, 'parameter2') );

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there will be no single quotes inside the `'...'`

```
Error_Msg\\.General_Message\\([^,]+,'(?![^']+:[a-zA-Z0-9])([^']*)'
```